# Where gen/R.java should be created in Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't know if this folder is existent at my project. I have already executed my application but I'm not finding this folder at my project. Where is it usually located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R.java will be automatically created for your project by android-studio once you build the project. 
You can find it at:

> your_app_name/app/build/generated/source/r/debug/your_package_name/R.java

You might not be seeing that folder in the project explorer of android-studio, because by default it's set to Android view. Change it to Project view.

[image: By default, project explorer shows Android view]

[image: Change it to Project View to have complete file view]

Answer (score 0):

The generated folder is under build of your projects app module.
Complete path of R for the debug is

> AppName/app/build/generated/source/r/debug/packagename/R.java

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the directory :

> app/build/generated/source/r/debug/package name

This file is automatically generated by the build process, so don't change it!